# set focus to input box and showing android keyboard using jquery mobile on pageshow

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to set focus to the input box and showing android keyboard using jquery mobile on pageshow.

I tried a lot of options from web. but none is working as expected in both emulator and mobile.

Here is the Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="main">
            <div data-role="header"><h3>Set Focus, Show Keyboard</h3></div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <label for="gotoPage"></label>
                <input type="text" name="gotoPage" id="gotoPage" placeholder="Question No." data-mini="true"   />
            </div>
        </div>                              

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).on('pageinit',"[data-role=page]", function() {  

            });

            $(document).on('pagebeforeshow',"[data-role=page]", function() {                

            });

            $(document).on('pageshow',"[data-role=page]", function() {  
                $('#gotoPage').focus().select();                        
            }); 
        </script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>      
    </body>
</html>
```

**Find the Screen shots for reference**

[image]

[image]

Kindly advice... Thanks in advance...

**NOTE:**

**As per Omar comment it is working fine in ios....
anyone can suggest how we get work this in android?**

Comment: I dont think the `select()` is needed

Comment: `$(document).on('pageshow',"[data-role=page]", function() { $('#gotoPage').trigger('click') });` you may need to set some delay using `setTimeout`.

Comment: can u please provide the exact code...

Comment: `$(document).on('pageshow', "[data-role=page]", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#gotoPage').trigger('click');
    }, 50);
});` forgot `;` after .trigger.

Comment: Sorry..i tried this, but its not working..

Comment: Hi Omar, Thanks for your quick reply.. but, still its not working.

Comment: Hey..Its working for me : http://jsbin.com/uqiheg/1..are u sure you did this right? i just removed the last `select()` from the code

Comment: Yeah its working fine in browser... not in emulator or mobile. The problem is not working mobile/emulator...

Comment: this method works on iphone, didn't try it on other mobiles.

Comment: I tried this on android 2.3. It's not working...any solution from anybody to get rid of this...

Answer (score 3):

The solution which works for me:

```
$("#main").on("pageshow" , function() {
$('#gotoPage').focus();
});
```